# Where can I find a Dutch record of birth for Louis Edward Schaap?

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, netherlands

I'm looking for a birth or civil record for Louis Edward Schaap. He was supposedly born in 'Holland' in abt 1845 according to the [1871](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:KZGJ-L97), [1881](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QKXG-KYGW) and [1891](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:7KLL-2W2) UK Census. [He married Clara Matilda Bish in 1876](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:2DPX-XVQ) and he died in [1897 in Leeds, Yorkshire](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:2JYD-HK1).

**1881 Census**:
[image: 1881 Census]

**1891 Census**:
[image: 1891 Census]

**Marriage Parish Register:**
[image: Marriage]

Comment: Worth noting, I only just found that 1871 record. Can't seem to find it anywhere on ancestry.

Comment: There's something a little odd there. The marriage cert has Clara's father as "Charles Bish". And the 1881 census has "Robert Peel" as "father-in-law", which should also mean Clara's father. Following "Peel" gives [this](http://interactive.ancestry.co.uk/7619/WRYRG10_4470_4474-0011?pid=26004962) 1871 census record (Ancestry) for Clara M Peel, which has not just the same parents as 1881 but also a right-aged Henrietta Peel too. But I see you have an 1861 census for Clara Bish. Are you certain that you're not mixing two Schaaps, as unlikely as it may seem?

Comment: @AndyW Father-in-law could also mean step-father in the past.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, I did not consider that. Robert Peel married Elizabeth Bish in Paris [in 1862](http://interactive.ancestry.co.uk/1993/41814_b157038-00070?pid=20291). My bad, sorry for the interruption. Thanks, @ColeValleyGirl

Comment: Father Edward Louis was a cloth merchant... The most important city for cloth making was Leiden (which is in the province of Holland, conveniently). Might that be where you find his record?

Comment: Guys we are 4 years on and you will find the answers to Louis Emanuel’s ( Levi Elias ) on my Ancestry . Co . UK family tree Newing for Mac. I’m interested in why you are researching this family ? You may be relatives of my wife ? Malcolm Newing

Answer (score 4):

I use WieWasWie at www.wiewaswie.nl. I think they started making their more advanced features subscription use only, but it's free to exact search. You do have to kind of play with it (I would try just last name and leave first name blank, and set the time period for births to 1840-1850 to narrow it). There are a good few Schaap births in there during that time period, but I'm thinking Louis must have been spelled differently in Dutch.

As an added update, I just saw this announcement on Dick Eastman's blog. The WieWasWie records are now searchable on Ancestry.com: 
https://blog.eogn.com/2016/06/09/ancestry-launches-100-million-dutch-records/

Answer (score 2):

Have you already looked at the [Zoekakten](http://zoekakten.nl/) website? There's a Familysearch [Wiki page](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Zoekakten) covering how to use it - it's all in Dutch and not particularly simple to navigate, but it works and the instructions help a lot.
I had a quick look at Amsterdam for the 1840s and found a selection of Schaaps but no Louis. The indices do appear to be alphabetised within 10 year blocks, but without knowing the location of his birth a search could be time-consuming. It may depend on if his census entry meant specifically ["Holland"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holland) (which is a part of the Netherlands, with its own North and South regions) or the Netherlands in general, which covers a lot more territory, of course.
Other than that, the base [NL](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Netherlands_Civil_Registration) wiki page at Familysearch has other options to try.

Comment: Note: Zoekakten was taken offline permanently July 2018

Answer (score 2):

I found a 'Levi Schaap' born in Amsterdam on October 5th 1844.
He's listed in the records from 1851-1853 and from 1853-1863, but he's absent in the records from 1874-1893.

Searching for 'Levi Schaap' and '1844' in MyHeritage, I found someone looking for 'Levi Elias Schaap' in combination with 'Clara Mathilda Schaap'. And I found [a profile on geni.com](https://www.geni.com/people/Levi-Schaap/6000000015383072083).

If this is the same person as the one you're looking for, you should be able to find a copy of his birth certificate in [these Amsterdam Archives](http://archief.amsterdam/).

Comment: Hi, alain -- I've made a small edit to clarify what your underlying link was at geni.com -- as much as possible, we would like to be able to understand what information is at the destination link before we click through to read it.